# localStroage of html5 store data in the form sql table is their any solutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use data in the form sql tables but i have to use locaStorage feature of html5 is their any way to stored data in the form sql

Comment: Thank you for response i am retrieving data from xml i want to store it in localstorage next time when page reload i will fetch data from localSrorage

Comment: could you give an example of data you want to store? Maybe a simple object is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557) for storage solutions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4695652/575527) briefly explains how the back-end of this library works.

As for data... Use JSON instead of XML. XML is too bulky to store, especially when the library falls back to cookie-based storage.

If you can't change how the server sends data (when the server guys are XML fanbois), here's an [XML to JSON library](http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html) which you try.