# Set Cookie with Javascript and sanitize value

Tags: javascript, cookies, special-characters

I need to set a cookie with javascript which I'm doing this with the following command:

```
document.cookie = name+"="+value;
```

My problem is that `value` is a string, which can contain any unicode-character.

Is there a function which automatically replaces special characters (like `;`) - and if not, which characters are forbidden?

Something like the "encodeURIComponent()"-Function for Get-Parameters would be perfect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`window.escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.escape).

> The escape() method converts special characters (any characters that are not regular text or numbers) into hexadecimal characters, which is especially necessary for setting the values of cookies. Also useful when passing name=value pairs in the URL of a GET request, or an AJAX GET/POST request.

It also has [`window.unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.unescape) counterpart.

**Upd.**
It may make some sense to use [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript#246813) encoding/decoding prior to escaping in order not to suffer that much from unicode characters expenditure by `window.encode`.

Comment: I have now a further problem: The size of my Cookie is >4kB
--> I can't store it
(This functions expands the content dramatically)

Comment: You could, for instance, get base64 of your values instead before putting them in a cookie - should take less space than encode result.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript#246813

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [a robust cookie library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to handle cookies?

```
$.cookie('key', value, { expires: 365 });
```

---

Browsers limit cookies to 4 kB.  If you need to store more than 4 kB on the client, you should use [local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4695652/201952).

Comment: I only need cookies for a small feature, and I don't want to include a complete jquery-plugin. This would be an overkill

Comment: @user1421312: You'll notice the plugin is 0.4 kB minified & gzipped -- hardly overkill.  This is a case where it's a good idea to just use a library so you can spend your time on more valuable things.  Also, cookies are limited to 4kB.  See edits about storing more than that.