# Syntax for using a cookie as an object

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, syntax, field

Trying to set a field name in a form.

```
SnapEngage.setCustomField(fieldName, fieldValue);
```

fieldName is the name of field on the form, I want to fill the fieldValue with the visitor's location_ID in their cookies using JavaScript. What would be the syntax for that object? I'm thinking something like self.location_ID but obviously it's not that.
I am not trying to set the cookie, rather use the cookie that is already set to fill in a form field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Cookie with Javascript and sanitize value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231731/set-cookie-with-javascript-and-sanitize-value)