# How to retain iframe src after refreshing the parent page using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am designing an application in ASP.NET which has a Master Page and a iframe. When I click on a link within the Master Page, the link is opened in the iframe, but if I refresh the parent page the iframe loses it's source and returns a blank frame.

How can I retain the iframe `src` attribute after refreshing the page like Parallel's Plesk Panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to temporary store the `URL` of the iframe and then retrieve it on the next page reload.

1. Store it as a cookie
2. Use `localStorage`
3. <strike>Use `window.name` -- er, no.  Ha.  Just kidding.  That is a bad hack.</strike>
4. Use one of the small packages that manage localStorage and default back to cookies if it must.

You might want to read [HTML5 Local Storage fallback solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692245/html5-local-storage-fallback-solutions) for more info on those options.