# Appending text to text file in javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to create my own type of blog style website where you post to a .txt file using javascript.

I have been encountering lots of trouble with this and have only managed to find a tiny part of what I want. Can you please help me!!!

Code:

```
<html><head>
<script language="javascript">
function Writedata()
  {
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var write_id;
write_id = document.getElementById('write_id').value ;
alert('The data has been written to \n' + write_id);
var s = fso.CreateTextFile(write_id, true);

s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('name_id').value);
s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('id_id').value);

s.Close();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
Date : <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name_id"><br/>
Address : <input type="text" name="id" value="" id="id_id"><br/>
Write file to : <input type="text" name="write" value="" id="write_id"><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="Writedata()" value="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

To reiterate the question, Please can you make the Date section add a date on webpage load and have the text from the address append to a file from the 'write file to' input.

Thanks!

Comment: What made you think you can write to the fileStorage from the browser?

Comment: Related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928117/how-to-use-filesystemobject-to-read-file-in-javascript . You cannot access the file system from your browser.

Comment: I have seen one work actually but it was not what I was looking for and I could not adapt it due to my little knowlage in javascript.

Comment: When did you see this .. 10 years ago? this makes little or no sense today.

Comment: But it writes to the text file but does not append it.

Comment: And I have found the working one yesterday actually

Comment: Then how would I do this to create what I want then?

Comment: You save the data serverside and make a AJAX request clientside. Or use any of the clientside storages such as cookies or localStorage. But do not proceed with this ActiveXObject, it pure crazyness and will not work in any browsers (except old IE)

Comment: so the only way to do this is to use local storage or cookies because I want to make it simple.

Comment: Well local storage and cookies are super simple so I bet that is exactly what you are looking for ;)

Comment: Okay great but what would happen if i use them? will it post to the actual inner html of the page or what?

Comment: They both allow you to persist data on the client (browser) and retrieve it at a later point (even after browser has been closed). What you do with the data, like put it inside some html or use it for calculation in the background or even send it to a remote server via sockets, is up to you. You should be able to find endless information and code samples on this subject

Comment: Okay but how would I do it? do you have a example of something I can test? because my knowlage of Local storage is even worse than that of javascript

Comment: If I use Local Storage will it display for other users?? because the whole point of it was to be a blog essentialy

Comment: You should be able to find the material you need. If you want to make a blog you will have to save the content serverside, then it will not work with cookies, localStorage or even file storage as you tried first. You need hosting.