# HTML5 localstorage fallback

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage, persistent-storage

I need to implement HTML5 local storage, and also provide support for users that dont have this available in their browser.

After doing some research, I came upon this post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692245/html5-local-storage-fallback-solutions), which offered exactly what I needed. In the solutions, someone mentioned [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557), which has a lot of fallback methods to save data if localStorage fails.

My question is, is this library still working properly? (No updates for over 2 years on the repository).

And also, maybe there are newer alternatives to achieving this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: nothing has changed in fallback storage for 5 years, two is not that old...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such questions always take a look at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills which lists polyfills for almost every new feature.

Which contains a list for LocalStorage as well https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-storage-localstorage-and-sessionstorage

In particular, this one seems active: https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js

Comment: After reading more about the subject, I will go with Store.js....

It has support for storing objects, just what I needed!

Thanks a lot