# alternative for localStorage and sessionStorage in IE10

Tags: local-storage, internet-explorer-10, session-storage, web-storage

I know `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` is not permitted in IE10 for local files (i.e) `file:///` protocol. but what is the alternative to store datas locally and retrieve them for local files? is there any other ways or plugins available?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692245/html5-local-storage-fallback-solutions) question has several fallback solutions listed. However, it's a few years old, so whether or not this will work with IE10... hm.

Aside from something like this or some sort of hackish behavior, it looks like your best bet is to just install a local stack. Somethings like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is really easy to get going for development purposes.