# Cookies, localStorage... What else?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cookies, local-storage

So I'm trying to save just under 7000 characters locally in whichever browser hits my page. iPhone is my #1 priority.

It doesn't seem like the cookie gets created. I've found that localStorage doesn't work with iOS 7.0.4 (with the bundled safari browser) so I've had to find a workaround. What else than LocalStorage and cookies are there? Something that would actually work for the iPhone.

Comment: AFAIK safari supports WebSQL http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

Comment: Does `localStorage` work on iOS [if you turn off private browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an)?

Comment: @Andy Nope, I've tried both with and without.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4695652/1001450 for a solution (PersistJS).

Comment: It's still not creating my one cookie that has the 7000 characters. Is there an option I need in order for it to store the data in chunks?

Comment: I saw this awnser (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692245/html5-local-storage-fallback-solutions) by josh3736. That will probably work beter. It has more fallback methods.

Comment: PersistJS is giving me an error in the source. Line 829 of persist.js  `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'init'`

Comment: Are you including it after including jQuery?

Comment: Yep, I figured it out though, just me being a dumbass and forgetting the `new` keyword.